# How to Remove Unwanted Top White Space in Mobile View on WordPress Index Page?

Tags: html, wordpress, mobile, responsive

Unwanted Top White Space [Mobile View] on index page

I tried to modify the code but was unable to find the source or solution, this is the url of the page: https://tebacaravaning.es/

When you see the page on mobile view, on the index page you see a white space, but on the other pages there is no white space. I tried with overflow hidden and overflow-x hidden, modify the height or width and nothing worked

[the problem on a image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc8jH.png)

Please could you help me resolve this problem

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most of such cases the problem should be found in one of the deeper elements that are located to the top of the page but have a `margin-top` set.

In this case it looks like there is a `margin-top` set to `.wp-block-uagb-container.uagb-block-f3352673`. If you reset this to zero, the gap will be gone.

The best would be to look for this block in the CMS or any other place where it will be set and see if you can change the settings for margin. If not, you can add this CSS:

```css
.wp-block-uagb-container.uagb-block-f3352673 {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

If you would like to have the space after all, but without the white thing on mobile, please change the `margin` to `padding` in order to have the same effect but with a blue background.

Comment: That was exactly the solution of the problem! Thanks a lot